# How can I fix my tic tac toe game so the screen runs correctly?

Tags: python, pygame

My tic-tac-toe pygame does not execute properly. What am I missing?

```py
import sys, pygame

from pygame.locals import *

import random

import time

import re

def setup_board(width=860,height=640):

    """A function for setting up a tic-tac-toe board, note that you have to call this multiple times if you draw over it"""

    size = width, height

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size) #sets up the screen to the size we want

    screen.fill('white')

    pygame.draw.line(screen, 'black', (width/3, 0), (width/3,height), 3)

    pygame.draw.line(screen, 'black', (2*width/3, 0), (2*width/3,height), 3)

    pygame.draw.line(screen, 'black', (0, height/3), (860,height/3), 3)

    pygame.draw.line(screen, 'black', (0, 2*height/3), (860,2*height/3), 3)

    return screen, width, height



def get_board_position(x, y):

    dw, dl = 860//3, 640//3

    return x//dw, y//dl, dw, dl



def get_draw_position(x, y):

    nx, ny, dw, dl = get_board_position(x, y)

    return nx*dw + dw/2, ny*dl + dl/2

def toss_coin():

    coin_states = ['heads', 'tails']

    return random.choice(coin_states)

def get_computer_move(board):

    for row in range(3):

        for col in range(3):

            if board[row][col] == '':

                return row, col

def get_player_move():

    """Returns the player move as a row and column"""

    valid_input = False

    while not valid_input:

        placement = input("Where would you like to play (enter as row,column e.g. 1,3)")

        match = re.search('[1,2,3],[1,2,3]', placement)

        valid_input = match is not None

        if valid_input:

            row, col = placement.split(',')

            row, col = int(row)-1, int(col)-1

            return row, col

def check_win(board):

    """Checks to see if there is a winner"""

    for row in range(3):

        if board[row][0] == board[row][1] == board[row][2] != '':

            return True

    for column in range(3):

        if board[0][column] == board[1][column] == board[2][column] != '':

            return True

    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] != '':

        return True

    elif board[2][0] == board[1][1] == board[0][2] != '':

        return True



    

def print_board(board):

    """This function will print a tic-tac-toe board to the console"""

    for index, row in enumerate(board):

        print('|'.join(row))

        if index < 2:

            print('-----')



    

        



pygame.init()

font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 110)

small_font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 30)

screen, width, height = setup_board()

clock=pygame.time.Clock()#gets the game clock, we are using this to ensure that we only run at 60fps       

rx = font.render("X", False, "black")

quit_text = small_font.render("Quit!", False, "red")

active_game = True

board = [['' ,'', ''], ['', '', ''],['', '', '']]

while active_game:

    quit_rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'gray', (50, 50, 60, 40), 1)

    screen.blit(quit_text, quit_rect)

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:

            ex, ey = event.pos

            if quit_rect[0] <= ex <= quit_rect[0] + quit_rect[2] and quit_rect[1] <= ey <= quit_rect[1] + quit_rect[3]:

                sys.exit()

            else:

                screen.blit(rx, get_draw_position(ex, ey))

    if check_win(board):

            active_game = False

            # replace with drawing winner to the screen

            print("You win!")

            time.sleep(6)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick_busy_loop( 60 )
```

Comment: *"does not execute properly"* could mean a lot of different things. Start by reading [ask] and [mcve], then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your feedback kaya3!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are converting this from a console app to a GUI app.  You are allowing clicks, but you are never entering them into your board array, so you can't check for wins, and you never let the computer move.